# How to draw a smooth line (small in some places, large in others) like in this image

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pen-tool, stroke

[image]

Check the image I attached above. I need to design a different logo. But need to draw it like this one because both the logos will be placed together (they need to match). So, anyone know how to draw the smooth line which is small in some places and large in others? How to add that effect? Im using Illustrator CS5.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply draw your paths then use the Width Tool:

[image: Width Tool]

You can click-drag a stroke to alter its width in Illustrator CS5 or CS6.

[image: Width]

Answer (score 2):

One way to make it is to construct every line from curves with Pen tool. I'd say a good approach is to start with a traditional pen-and-paper sketch, showing which parts of the lines are thick or thin, and then duplicating it in vector form in Illustrator.

[image: Weighted line made from bezier curves]

Someone handy with a pressure sensitive tablet should be able to reproduce good weighed lines with the brush tools too, but it might be a bit tricky to find proper settings for the brush.

Comment: Re. *"Someone handy with a pressure sensitive tablet should be able to reproduce good weighed lines with the brush tools too, but it might be a bit tricky to find proper settings for the brush."* - `Blob Brush` is the tool you want - double click and link 'Size' to 'Pressure' at the bottom, then up `variation` to close to maximum. But, wow, that's one difficult technique to master. Great for free, loose expressive stuff.

Comment: @user568458 Thanks for the tip, I've learned plenty in this question post so far! Illustrator isn't the easiest one to approach, so I've kinda ignored it for artsy stuff. I can already see the potential in this... :-)